Working with data from a large number of csv files in Python
I have 101 .csv files, each with 10001 pairs of values (an example of such a file in the picture is the dependence of the spectral power density on frequency - Example). I need to somehow square the values of the 2nd column in each of the files and then average these values (averaging occurs between the values of one row number. I.e. we take from all 101 files the squared values of the 2nd column of one row and average them, and so with all other rows. In other words, the dependencies should be averaged over spectral power densities).
How can this be accomplished?
So far, at the moment I have only been able to process one file, and at the same time, the graph of the dependence of one file (without squaring) looks like such a nightmare.
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Den\Desktop\SPD\tek0000MTH.csv', sep = ';')


x = data['W'].to_numpy()
y = data['S'].to_numpy()

plt.xlabel('w') 
plt.ylabel('S') 
plt.title('SPD') 
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.grid() 
plt.show()

Plot
At the same time, I cannot imagine how to perform all the above tasks, such as squaring and averaging, working with 101 files at once.

Concatenate all csv files into one dataframe, groupby:
import os
import pandas as pd
csv_folder = r"/home/bera/Desktop/gistest/csvs/" #The folder with the 102 csv files, and nothing else.

#Find and create a dataframe of each csv file
frame_list = []
for root, folder, files in os.walk(csv_folder):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith("csv"):
            fullname = os.path.join(root, file)
            df = pd.read_csv(fullname, sep=";")
            df["filename"] = file #Store the filename as a value
            frame_list.append(df) 
print(len(frame_list))
#102

megaframe = pd.concat(frame_list, axis=0) #Concatenate the 102 frames into one
print(megaframe.shape)
#(1020000, 3)

print(megaframe.sample(3))
#                  w         s     filename
# 3940    884.419539  0.018198  file_93.csv
# 6314   1526.922029  0.013237   file_4.csv
# 3322  18177.653004  0.003916  file_51.csv

megaframe["s_sq"] = megaframe["s"]**2
df_means = megaframe.groupby("filename", as_index=False)["s_sq"].mean()
print(df_means.head())
#        filename      s_sq
# 0    file_0.csv  0.000134
# 1    file_1.csv  0.000135
# 2   file_10.csv  0.000132
# 3  file_100.csv  0.000135
# 4  file_101.csv  0.000132


some questions about the results. After checking the random samples that are given to me, I noticed that the line numbers of the values that python gives out do not correspond to those in the file (the line number is always less than 2). For example: 182  455.0  0.003791  tek0004MTH.csv is actually 184  455.0  0.003791  tek0004MTH.csv. As I understand it, python rightly does not take into account the string with w,s; but it turns out that it also does not take into account the very first value at zero?
